# Snap VSCode no space left on device

Tags: snap, mate, ubuntu-mate, visual-studio-code

I have installed snapcraft's VSCode for a long time.
It has crashed like this before but I had managed to fix that by setting:

```
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
```

But now it has crashed much severe. When I try to start vscode using `code --verbose` this is what I get:

```
amir@amir-pc:~$ code --verbose
(process:20078): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:08:48.237: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[20104:1010/150848.496732:ERROR:gl_context_glx.cc(227)] Couldn't make context current with X drawable.
[20104:1010/150848.496791:ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(68)] gl::GLContext::MakeCurrent() failed
[20104:1010/150848.496808:ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(185)] Could not create context for info collection.
[20104:1010/150848.496824:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(64)] gpu::CollectGraphicsInfo failed.
[20104:1010/150848.499694:WARNING:x11_util.cc(1430)] X error received: serial 199, error_code 2 (BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)), request_code 155, minor_code 24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
[20104:1010/150848.500364:WARNING:x11_util.cc(1430)] X error received: serial 200, error_code 170 (GLXBadContext), request_code 155, minor_code 5 (X_GLXMakeCurrent)
[20104:1010/150848.501840:WARNING:x11_util.cc(1430)] X error received: serial 200, error_code 170 (GLXBadContext), request_code 155, minor_code 26 (X_GLXMakeContextCurrent)
[20104:1010/150848.501987:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(170)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[20104:1010/150848.503057:WARNING:x11_util.cc(1430)] X error received: serial 201, error_code 170 (GLXBadContext), request_code 155, minor_code 4 (X_GLXDestroyContext)
[20078:1010/150848.507698:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1193)] The GPU process has crashed 1 time(s)
[main 2020-10-10T11:38:48.537Z] Error: listen ENOSPC: no space left on device /run/user/1000/snap.code/vscode-6ecfff7c-1.40.2-main.sock
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1209:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1274:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1373:5)
    at /snap/code/21/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:194:613
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.t.serve (/snap/code/21/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:194:550)
    at Object.doStartup (/snap/code/21/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:544:732)
    at /snap/code/21/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:543:220
    at h.invokeFunction (/snap/code/21/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:255:601)
    at Object.startup (/snap/code/21/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:543:56)
[main 2020-10-10T11:38:48.540Z] Lifecycle#kill()
```

At first I thought by clearing the contents of `/run/user/1000/` things would become fine. But after doing `cd /run/user/1000/ ; rm -rf *` (Which is somehow dangerous) actually the OS's window manager (Its Ubuntu mate so its `lightdm`) crashed. I managed to bring it up and get it working again by restarting its service, But again the problem persists with VSCode. Same error is given to me again.

This is the output of `df -h` on my system:

```
amir@amir-pc:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.2G  2.1M  1.2G   1% /run
/dev/sda1        73G   45G   25G  65% /
tmpfs           5.8G  109M  5.7G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      8.0M  8.0M     0 100% /snap/pulsemixer/23
/dev/loop1      256K  256K     0 100% /snap/gtk2-common-themes/5
/dev/loop2      154M  154M     0 100% /snap/chromium/958
/dev/loop3      150M  150M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/71
/dev/loop5       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/8592
/dev/loop7       88M   88M     0 100% /snap/go/4520
/dev/loop6      173M  173M     0 100% /snap/skype/100
/dev/loop8       34M   34M     0 100% /snap/pypy3/50
/dev/loop4      153M  153M     0 100% /snap/chromium/1026
/dev/loop9       32M   32M     0 100% /snap/pypy/30
/dev/loop10      90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8039
/dev/loop11      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/remmina/3223
/dev/loop12      72M   72M     0 100% /snap/software-boutique/31
/dev/loop16     128K  128K     0 100% /snap/software-boutique/39
/dev/loop14     203M  203M     0 100% /snap/vlc/1049
/dev/loop17      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1265
/dev/loop15     175M  175M     0 100% /snap/inkscape/5874
/dev/loop13     203M  203M     0 100% /snap/vlc/1397
/dev/loop19      34M   34M     0 100% /snap/pypy/40
/dev/loop18      16M   16M     0 100% /snap/ubuntu-mate-welcome/420
/dev/loop20      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1668
/dev/loop21     8.0M  8.0M     0 100% /snap/pulsemixer/250
/dev/loop22      32M   32M     0 100% /snap/pypy3/37
/dev/loop23      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/remmina/3810
/dev/loop24     256K  256K     0 100% /snap/gtk2-common-themes/9
/dev/loop25     137M  137M     0 100% /snap/code/21
/dev/loop26      45M   45M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1353
/dev/loop28      16M   16M     0 100% /snap/ubuntu-mate-welcome/411
/dev/loop27     220M  220M     0 100% /snap/gimp/189
/dev/loop29      45M   45M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1440
/dev/loop30     175M  175M     0 100% /snap/inkscape/4693
/dev/sda3       608G  557G   21G  97% /mnt/9c710070-854e-463f-80bf-b291852869ba
tmpfs           1.2G   76K  1.2G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Basically I have kept my computer running for almost 28 days. I mean I just suspend and resumed it (Because of some hardware problem it takes effort to start it when it shuts down, It can not be restarted, so I am suspending and resuming it for a long time now).
I know this may sound funny, But currently I don't have the incentives to fix anything.

Could this 28 nonstop days of using ram caused this issue? Could it be causing so many garbage files to be created and ultimately preventing other processes from having space on hard drive / ram ?

My computer ram is almost free:
[image]
I can not conclude ram has no space left on it.

I know how to supress the problem. By RESTARTING MY LAPTOP.
But that's not how the problem is fixed. Its SUPPRESSING.

Does anybody knows how to fix this problem?
Chromium (Snap Chromium) runs, Telegram runs, Libreoffice works. But VSCode and Mate desktop apps crash.

Another process died just now: (Looks like my computer is self-destructing)
[image]

Thanks for any help.
Im using Ubuntu Mate 18.04.

Comment: Disk space is not a real issue here. Please add output of `snap list | grep code` along with `lspci -k | grep -E "VGA|3D|Video" -A2` and `dpkg -l libgl1-mesa-dri`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my laptop got into problems with its graphics card and could not start after that.

I sent it to be fixed, and now its fine.